# How can we show the Inverse map from GL(E) to L(E) is twice differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've seen some formulas for the first derivative where

$Df^{-1}$= $\frac{1}{Df*(f^{-1})}$

But I'm stuck on the next steps. Is there an easy way to arrive at higher derivatives as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then what you are referring to is the [(single-variable) inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). This is the only context where what you wrote really makes sense. You don't specify what "next steps" you are stuck on, so I can't comment on that. I don't really know what your title means too.